# Can not access SQL 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

the SQL has been installed but there is no server name and the Program does not accept any server name , and all the options , like the TCP , ports and Remote access are enabled

Comment: i mean that after i start it i should enter a server name but there is no server name and it does not accept any name

Comment: What is "it"..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot Connect to the SQL Server , SQL 2005 and it doesnot want to connect to the server and there is no Server name ? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022136/cannot-connect-to-the-sql-server-sql-2005-and-it-doesnot-want-to-connect-to-the)

Comment: SQL-ServerName is per default the Name of the Server where SQLServer is installed. If you don't have a active directory use the TCP/IP-Address instead of a servername. Do not forget the name of the instance if one is installed...

Answer (score 0):

Points to consider:

```
  (1) Is the firewall configured to allow traffic on ports 1433 & 1434?
  (2) Is the SQL Server Browser service started?
  (3) Is the SQL Server configured to allow remote connections?
```

Check these out and be sure to update this post with your results.